# How to remove a product from a specific website by uploading a CSV file

Tags: product, csv, store-view, multi-website

Currently, I want to delete products from a specific website in bulk, as it is a huge list of SKU's, So I want to do this via a CSV file.

But I have not identified which field removes the check mark from the website I want to delete from.

Below is the illustration I am referring to.

[image]

Here is a visual example of how I have placed it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Solution.

In the CSV file, add a column `product_websites` column e.g = `base` and Import.
So once this is imported successfully, Verify it.

Try with 1 or 2 product first.